# How to reverse engineer a weighted five star distribution when given its average value?

Tags: php, math, rating

I'll illustrate this in PHP but the question is more or less language agnostic.

I have the average rating for a product that has been voted on using a five-star rating system. Let's say for this product `$averageRating = 3.43`. I would like to create a mock distribution of votes that could create this average. Here is how the average might be determined given you already have the vote distribution:

```
            $distribution = array(
                1 => $oneStarVotes,
                2 => $twoStarVotes,
                3 => $threeStarVotes,
                4 => $fourStarVotes,
                5 => $fiveStarVotes
            );

            foreach ($distribution as $key => $value) {
                $weightedTotal += $key * $value;
            }

            $totalVotes = array_sum($distribution);

            $averageRating = $weightedTotal / $totalVotes;
```

Can anyone think of a way to reverse engineer this so you could create values for the variables `$oneStarVotes, $twoStarVotes...etc.` given you have `$averageRating`?

Comment: I don't imagine so, that would involve recreating information from a lossy source (think 'zoom' from CSI). And the presence of an average doesn't imply weighting, nor the number of total voters.

Comment: Reference (of many): ['enhance button,' CSI (TV Tropes)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EnhanceButton).

Comment: oh god. algebra. *runs away*

Comment: You say create a 'mock distribution'. Is that to mean simply any distribution at all that amounts to that average? or are you hoping to recover a distribution within some bounded margin of error of the true votes? (The latter obviously much more difficult).

Comment: Also, why do you need to assume a weighted average? Why not simple arithmetic mean?

Comment: @DuckMaestro: any distribution really

Comment: @DuckMaestro: would you care to share a solution using a simple arithmetic mean?

Comment: @jcroll Working one out now... Just making sure I have enough relevant context.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for any distribution, this is a simple problem of algebra and thinking about finding reasonable whole numbers.

I would approach the problem as follows (in pseudo code):

```
Case 1: avg = 1.0
    distribution <- { x1, 0, 0, 0, 0 } for any positive integer x1.

Case 2: avg = 5.0
    distribution <- { 0, 0, 0, 0, x5 } for any positive integer x5.

Case 3: avg is within (1.0, 5.0)
    distribution = { x1, 0, 0, 0, x5 } for some positive integers x1 and x5.
```

In other words, simplify the problem to choosing vote counts for 1-star and 5-star votes only.

To solve for `x1` and `x5` in case 3 you need to choose `x1` and `x5` that satisfy the equation for arithmetic mean among votes of only 1-star and 5-star:

```
(1 * x1 + 5 * x5) / (x1 + x5) = avg
```

It helps to instead solve for `x1` and `T`, where `T` is a total number of votes (`x1 + x5 = T`).

Via algebra the above can be written as

```
x1 = T * (5 - avg) / 4
```

You could arbitrarily pick a value for `x1` and solve for `T`, but this won't guarantee that `T` is an integer.

However, by picking a sufficiently large value of `x1`, you can *round* `T` with less error than if `x1` were small.

For example, if `avg = 3.43` (as is given in your question), and we arbitrarily pick `x1 = 100`, then we get

```
avg      = 3.43
x1       = 100
T        = 254.78
TRounded = 255
x5       = 155
```

When you plug these values back into the arithmetic mean you get

```
(1 * 100 + 5 * 155)/255 = 3.431
```

which equals the original `avg` in this case, up to 2 decimal places. The end formula for case 3 then is

```
Case 3 (cont.):
    x1 <- (a large enough integer)
    T  <- round (x1 * 4 / (5 - avg))
    x5 <- T - x1
    distribution <- { x1, 0, 0, 0, x5 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately (if I understand your solution correctly) this will create very odd looking distributions, ones that human eyes will instantly recognize as "strange" because there will only be values for one star votes and five star votes am I right? Imagine putting the data into graphs like the ones Amazon has [here](http://www.amazon.com/Merry-Christmas-Cross-James-Patterson/product-reviews/0316210684/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_pop_hist_all?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1). I did say any distribution so that is my bad, I didn't conceive of such an extreme solution! I do thank you very much for your answer.